# Scikitklearns TfidfTransformer makes my pipeline predict just one label

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification

I have a pandas dataframe containing texts and labels, and I'm trying to predict the labels using scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer`, `TfidfTransformer` and `MultinomialNB`. Here's what the dataframe looks like:

```
                                                text party
0  Herr ålderspresident! Att vara talman i Sverig...     S
1  Herr ålderspresident! Ärade ledamöter av Sveri...     M
2  Herr ålderspresident! Som företrädare för Alli...     M
3  Val av andre vice talman Herr ålderspresident!...    SD
4  Herr ålderspresident! Vänsterpartiet vill utny...     V
```

When I construct a pipeline with the three estimators mentioned above, I only get a ~35% accuracy in my predictions, but when I remove the `TfidfTransformer` the accuracy is bumped up to a more reasonable ~75% accuracy.

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), # problematic row
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
                   ])

text_clf = text_clf.fit(df.text.values, df.party.values)

test = df.sample(500, random_state=42)
docs_test = test.text.values
predicted = text_clf.predict(docs_test)
np.mean(predicted == test.party.values)
# Out: either 0.35 or 0.75 depending on whether I comment out the problematic row above
```

When I get 0.35 and inspect `predicted` I see that it almost exclusively contains one label ('S'). This is the most common label in the original dataset, but that shouldn't impact the predictions, right? Any ideas on why I get these strange results?

**EDIT**: [Link to data](https://gist.github.com/miroli/3ac8f5c6b6f4ed786189685b327e45ad) where `anforandetext` and `parti` are the relevant columns.

Comment: Why are you testing on the same data that you are using to train your model? This is a big No-No in Machine Learning. Though, this might be unrelated but you should use cross-validation to get accuracy estimates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting so much difference is because of smoothing. If you checkout the documentation of [MultinomialNB class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html), checkout the `alpha` parameter. The default value for that is `1.0`. This means that it implements Plus One smoothing by default. Plus one smoothing is a very common technique used with relative frequency estimates to account for unseen data. In Plus One smoothing, we add `1` to all raw counts to account for unseen terms and the sparsity of the document-term matrix.

However, when you end up using TF-IDF weights, the numbers that you get are very small and mostly between 0 - 1. To illustrate, if I use your data and only convert it into TF-IDF weights, this is the small snapshot of the TF-IDF weights that I obtain.

```
  (0, 80914)    0.0698184481033
  (0, 80552)    0.0304609466459
  (0, 80288)    0.0301759343786
  (0, 80224)    0.103630302925
  (0, 80204)    0.0437500703747
  (0, 80192)    0.0808649191625
```

You can see that these are really small numbers and adding 1 to them for smoothing will have a drastic effect on the calculations that Multinomial Naive Bayes makes. By adding 1 to these numbers, you completely change their scale for classification and hence your estimates mess up. I am assuming, you have a good idea about how Multinomial Naive Bayes works. If not, then definitely see this [video](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/28). The video and my answer will be sufficient to understand what is going wrong over here.

You should either use a small value of `alpha` in TF-IDF case or you should build TF-IDF weights after doing smoothing on the raw counts. Also on a secondary note, please use cross-validation to get any accuracy estimates. By testing the model on a sample of the training data, your accuracy numbers will be extremely biased. I would recommend using cross-validation or a separate hold-out set to evaluate your model.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!